# How to display HyperLink Data in JTable column?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-jtable

I want to display a href to the data received from jtable.

Below is the code snippet.

```
$('#JarDistHist').jtable({
    title: 'Jar Distribution History',
    paging: true,
    //pageSize: 10,
    sorting: true,
    defaultSorting: 'Date ASC',
    actions: {
        listAction: 'StudentActions.php?action=list&DistId=' + cname + '&fitem=' + fitem + '',


        deleteAction: 'StudentActions.php?action=delete'
    },
    fields: {
        id: {

            key: true,
            create: false,
            edit: false,
            list: false,

        },
        Date: {
            title: ' Date',
            type: 'date',
            displayFormat: 'dd-mm-y',
            width: '40%',
            options: '<a href="JarFillingDetail.php?id">'
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on this link : http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/WebDev/ServerProgramming/nancy-and-jtable-formatting-your/

I think this is what you want.

Add field `display`.

> When we configure our fields for jtable we have a display attribute
>   that takes a function and in that function we can do our formatting.

```
display: function (data) {
                            return $('<a href="JarFillingDetail.php?id="' + data.Id + '"></a>');
                         }
```

Comment: HI I have added the above display: function to the code for date bt the date   displayFormat: 'dd-mm-y', option is not formating the date :(

Comment: @ShoyebShaikh, http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/WebDev/ServerProgramming/nancy-and-jtable-formatting-your/ 2nd paragraph tells how to solve this problem. Add ` moment.js` file to your project and add this code for formating : `display: function (data) {
                                return moment(data.Date).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
                            }` Hopes this helps, because i never used jTable :) Date format please set that you need